# Chartjs autocolors not working as expected with dataset

Tags: chart.js

Autocolors plugin is not working as expected with chartjs. It does not assign different colors.

```js
const autocolors = window['chartjs-plugin-autocolors'];

var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7]
      },
      {
        label: '# of People',
        data: [3, 1, 15, 4, 9, 12]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      autocolors: {
         mode: 'dataset'
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-autocolors"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because you never registered the plugin, if you do that it works fine:

```js
const autocolors = window['chartjs-plugin-autocolors'];

Chart.register(autocolors);

var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7]
      },
      {
        label: '# of People',
        data: [3, 1, 15, 4, 9, 12]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      autocolors: {
         mode: 'dataset'
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-autocolors"></script>
</body>
```